# Beam.BigQueryIO: What is numFileShards for?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I wanted to load my unbound input from Kafka to BigQuery, I came across `.withMethod()`  option. By using Method.FILE_LOAD , I have to also specify the triggering frequency as well as a non-zero numFileShards.

**My questions are**:

1. What does number of file shards control? what does it extactly used for? To my observation, it's definitely not the nubmer of temp files generated on my GCS temp location and visible to me. But I wonder what number I should choose to set here?
2. According to the source code I quote bellow, the default value should be 1000, but actually it is 0, so I got an exception when I didn't set it explicitly and when I set it to 1, the exception was gone, but again, I don't  understand what it is and what I am setting for, lol

> ```
> /**Control how many file shards are written when using BigQuery load jobs. 
>  Applicable only when also setting {@link/#withTriggeringFrequency}.
>  The default value is 1000.*/
>
> @Experimental
> public Write<T> withNumFileShards(int numFileShards) {
>   checkArgument(numFileShards > 0, "numFileShards must be > 0, but was: %s", numFileShards);
>   return toBuilder().setNumFileShards(numFileShards).build();
> }
> ```

3. Is there a way that I can specify batch size by record count instead of by time Duration?

Exception that I got when I didn't set NumFileShards:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.expandTriggered(BatchLoads.java:212)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.expand(BatchLoads.java:557)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.expand(BatchLoads.java:79)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:471)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expandTyped(BigQueryIO.java:1656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1602)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1068)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:488)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:338)
    at come.geotab.bigdata.streaming.mapenrichedgps.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:119)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing data to BigQuery can work in different ways. `FILE_LOAD` means that Beam will write your windowed `PCollection` into Avro files, and then it will trigger a BigQuery job to import the contents of those files.

The number of file shards controls how many files your `PCollection` will be written to, and thus the parallelism of the BQ import job.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have guessed this meaning, but when I set it to 1, but I got 3 files in the temp location -- which caused my confusion.  Also, the triggering frequency decides how many load jobs will be triggered, and I don't think an incomplete  file can be loaded, so in this sense I can't make sense of letting me control the number of files there.

Comment: Are you sure the 3 files are not from different times a job was triggered? I'd think the numShards should control the number of shards _per trigger_

Comment: "shards per trigger" can make sense to me. I'll watch it and see

Comment: [Java BigQuery IO.Write class](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html), just for completion.